# Jest mock onPress for react native

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have a function that I can test because it is exported, ie.

```
const export myFunction = parameters => mockableFunction(parameters);
```

but when I use it in an `onPress` event that takes a parameter, I have to create an anonymous function like this:

```
<Button onPress={ () => myFunction(parameters) } />
```

How do I go about testing the anonymous function generated in the button component? It seems trivial but it's lowering my coverage, which is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What library are you using?
With enzyme you can call `wrapper.find(Button).first().simulate('press')` or (maybe more reliable) `wrapper.find(Button).first().props().onPress()`